# Зачем в статическом методе делать локальные переменные финальными?

Tags: android, java

В одном из стандартных примеров — SampleSyncAdapter — есть такой фрагмент:

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password, Handler handler, **final Context context**) {
    **final HttpResponse resp;**

    **final ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();**
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_USERNAME, username));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PARAM_PASSWORD, password));
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
    } catch (**final UnsupportedEncodingException e**) {
        // this should never happen.
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
    **final HttpPost post = new HttpPost(AUTH_URI);**
    ...
```

Далее также некоторые переменные помечены как final. Зачем?

Answer (score 32):

Дело не в статическом методе, `final` может использовать везде. Есть 2 причины использования `final`:

1. Когда компилятор встречает ключевое слово `final`, то он пытается делать оптимизацию кода имея ввиду, что значение этой переменной далее не будет меняться. Кое-какие копейки (экономия стека или быстродействия) за счет такой оптимизации можно выиграть.
2. Кроме того программист сознательно может использовать слово `final` с тем, чтобы контролировать уже на этапе компиляции будет меняться его значение или нет. То есть если будет попытка модификации присвоенного при инициализации значения компилятор выдаст ошибку. Некоторым девелоперам кажется, что это айс.
3. Эта переменная будет захватываться анонимным классом (Верно для версий меньших 8). Для того что бы захватить переменные в контекст они должны быть помечены как final. Начиная с 8 версии компилятор сам может определять является ли переменная неизменяемой (effectively final) и ключевое слово становиться необязательно.

Answer (score 9):

Пример для демонстрации сказанного [Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley) (п.2):

```
final int a = 1;
a = 2; // нельзя

final int b;
b = 3; // можно
b = 4; // нельзя
```

Comment: Т.е. final переменной первый раз можно присвоить значение(к примеру, по нажатию, на кнопку), а второй раз уже нет, верно ?

Answer (score 2):

Если переменная объявлена как final, то её значение не изменяется в рантайме. Это позволяет программисту быть уверенным,что значение переменной не поменяется т.е. переменная является константой, например если вам нужно число Пи - вам же не нужно чтобы число Пи поменялось. (конечно его можно взять из класса Math, если поставленная задача того требует).

Если немного конкретнее:

Значение переменной файнал присваивается только 1 раз или сразу при объявлении или в конструкторе. Даже если вы будете пытаться присвоить переменной такое же значение, которое в ней уже находится, компилятор всё равно ругнется.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово final так же важно и с точки зрения `Java Memory Model`.

Для ясности, покажу на коде:

```
class A {
   private Object field = new Object();
}
```

Если данный объект создан в одном потоке и передается в другой, то `JMM` не гаратирует, что поле `field` будет не равно `null`. Для избежания данной ситуация используется `final`. Это дает некоторые гарантии, не используя синхронизацию, увидеть в разных потоках полностью проинициализированный объект.